# Error 438 when setting an object variable to a subform path

Tags: vba, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

Hi all I trying to setup an object variable to pass into a module. I'm getting the Run-time error 438 in the first case below but not in the second. Can anyone say why?

```
Private Sub OpGenericText_AfterUpdate()
    Dim obCurrentForm As Object
    Set obCurrentForm = Forms.AssemblyProcesses.APSectionsSubForm.APStepsSubForm
    Call UpdateStepText(obCurrentForm)
End Sub
```

the following works

```
Private Sub OpGenericText_AfterUpdate()
    Dim obCurrentForm As Object
    Set obCurrentForm = Forms.StepsWhereUsedWithDetail
    Call UpdateStepText(obCurrentForm)
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `APSectionsSubForm`? An enum? Is `Forms` built-in or your own helper class? I can't find `Forms.AssemblyProcesses` on Google.

Comment: APSectionsSubForm is a form in the AssemblyProcesses form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably read as it seems as you have nested subforms:

```
Private Sub OpGenericText_AfterUpdate()
    Dim obCurrentForm As Form
    Set obCurrentForm = Forms!AssemblyProcesses!NameOfFirstSubformControl.Form!NameOfSecondSubformControl.Form
    Call UpdateStepText(obCurrentForm)
End Sub
```